# Why is my Ajax not sending the information to the external file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

The idea is I am sending data to an external php via ajax, where that external php will create a pdf using tcpdf, and then return that pdf to me. But something's wrong.

I can't see where the mistake lies. Basically, I'm trying to send two pieces of information via ajax. The first is a full string of html markup which I assign to it using the `.html()` function. The second is just a test to see if it would also get sent or not.

The JQuery looks like this (the problem lies in the PDF button):

```
$(".pdf-report").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: 700,
    height: 650,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: {
        "PDF": function(){
            /*
            var send_html = $('#query_result').html();
            $.post('pdfajax.php',
                {
                    qch: 'TESTQCH',
                    code: send_html
                },
                function( data ){
                    $('#report_result').html(data); // assuming there is a div with id result
                }
            );
            */
            var send_html = $('#report_result').html();
            alert(send_html);
            $('#ireport_result').prop('src', 'pdfajax.php?send_html='+send_html);

        },
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

And the external file, pdfajax.php, looks like this:

```
    require_once 'core/init.php';
require_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

$html = input::get('send_html');

//echo 'test ',var_dump($qch),'<br />',var_dump($html);

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//echo $method;
if(strtolower($method) == 'post'){

$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, 'C');


$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

I know nothing gets sent because this is the result (the blank iframe, not the text above it):
[image]

Oh yes and the input class has the get function which simply says this:

```
    public static function get($item){
    if(isset($_POST[$item])){
        return $_POST[$item];
    } elseif (isset($_GET[$item])){
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="pdf-report" title="Report Dialog">
<br />
<div id="report_result"></div>
<iframe src="tcpdf/examples/example_001.php" id="ireport_result"></iframe>
<br />
```

Comment: Using the console (or tools like FireBug) helps identifying ajax requests, most of the time it either doesn't get fired or you'll get a 404 or 500 status code.

Comment: It sends it in the console. I don't know if it just doesn't render in the TCPDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, there is an issue with your ajax call. Your `$.post` appears to be fine. But the issue might be because of your success callback handler.

You are setting the pdfajax.php as the source of your iframe after your ajax request has completed successfully, which doesn't make any sense. Because, this would trigger a new **GET** request to the URL 'pdfajax.php' and it wouldn't contain any request parameters at all.

Ideally, your data object would be containing the response received from 'pdfajax.php' which you can use to display within a div or so.

```
function( data ){
    $('#report_result').html(data); // this can be used for html response not for pdf.
}
```

But in case, you want the data in your iframe, i don't think there is a need for Ajax. You can directly set the src for the iframe as shown below.

```
    $(".pdf-report").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: 700,
    height: 650,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: {
        "PDF": function(){
            var send_html = $('#report_result').html();
            $('#ireport_result').prop('src', 'pdfajax.php?code='+send_html);
        },
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

And your php file has few issues. The request parameter is `code` not `send_html` and your request type is `GET` not `POST`.

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
require_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
$html = input::get('code');

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if(strtolower($method) == 'get'){
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, 'C');
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Comment: This worked by making the program do a function successfully, but they don't return the pdf successfully. I changed the selectors to agree with the html. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w252oijxzz0ub8o/Screenshot%202014-03-10%2021.21.29.png This is the result of the first code. The next image is the result of the second code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w27sfe3v019jua6/Screenshot%202014-03-10%2021.23.16.png

Comment: I edited the post to include the html. You were right in saying it's an iframe. I tweaked the code a bit so that the ID of the div would be "report_result" while the iframe ID would be "ireport_result"

Comment: You cannot set a pdf within a div. Since you are trying to output the pdf content directly into a div, you get that gibberish stuff in the first image. Try the second code with #ireport_result instead of #report_result

Comment: I'm trying it but it doesn't work, it shows this result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w27sfe3v019jua6/Screenshot%202014-03-10%2021.23.16.png. I'll update the original post to show the code I'm now using.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way, it looks like the right direction to me

Comment: It works! I'm not sure what I did wrong, it was probably the post. I did update the request parameter into send_html in my code (I updated my jQuery in my original post). Thanks so much! I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days now. It turns out I don't even need Ajax.